# Roblox Gui Toggles On/Off only on the First click

Tags: user-interface, toggle, roblox

My gui turns on when touching an NPC. It shows an "Off" button. When the off button is clicked the first time, it turns off the gui by setting the frame.Visible = false and the gui.Enabled = false.

When I touch the NPC again, the gui shows, as it should. Though the button doesn't cause the properties to be set to false. I have outputted the value of frame.Visible and it prints "False", though in the Properties window, the value is shown to be "True".

What is going on here?

```
--NPC Script
local soldier = game.Workspace["Level6"].Soldier.Humanoid.RootPart
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local function onTouch(touchPart)
    if touchPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        local gui = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.EndScreenGui
        local frame = gui.Frame

        frame.Visible = true
        gui.Enabled = true
        print("On")
    end
end

soldier.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

And here is my gui code:

```
local button = script.Parent

function onClicked()
    local frame = button.Parent
    local gui = frame.Parent

    --frame.Visible = false
    gui.Enabled = false
    print(frame.Visible)
end

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(onClicked)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we do syntax higlighting we can see this:

```lua
function onClicked()
    local frame = button.Parent
    local gui = frame.Parent

    --frame.Visible = false
    gui.Enabled = false
    print(frame.Visible)
end
```

The `frame.Visible` line is commented off, so it doesn't run. Remove the `--` before that line and your script should be all good.